# Tearable cloth with javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

Just today at http://codepen.io/dissimulate/pen/KrAwx i found Tearable cloth. There are javascript laibraries which I don't understand

```
window.requestAnimFrame =
window.requestAnimationFrame ||
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
```

I don't even know where to start with anything like this.Can someone advice me a book or step by step tutorials  which will include all the javascript which is given at the given example? Thanks a lot!
One more is here: http://codepen.io/andremichelle/pen/yIkzx

Comment: Welcome. I haven't used it, but you could start [here](https://www.google.co.za/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tearable+cloth+js+getting+started). Come back and let us know how it goes.

Comment: thanks :) i think now i know from where to start :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/

That will help walk you through some cool animations you can do. It should help you get on your way to designing cool stuff like what was on Codepen.